# Why causes tmux 2.1 to set EVENT_NOEPOLL?

Tags: tmux, epoll, libevent

On two machines that are identical in kernel version and hardware, I start a `tmux` session, and type `env`.

On one machine, I see `EVENT_NOEPOLL=1`. On the other one, I do not see this line. This behavior persists across reboots.

What might cause `tmux` to set the variable in one case but not the other?

**Edit:** I found the source code, but I still do not understand *why* it is set only sometimes.

```
struct event_base *
osdep_event_init(void)
{
    /* On Linux, epoll doesn't work on /dev/null (yes, really). */
    setenv("EVENT_NOEPOLL", "1", 1);
    return (event_init());
}
```